# Solving heat equation with heaviside function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, heat-equation

I want to solve a heat equation (assumed a.o. that the time derivative equals zero):
$u_{xx}=-(H(x-0.3)-H(x-0.7))$. I let some constants out, because these don't matter for the solving method. Note $u(0)=200, u(1)=400, u_x(0)=0$.

To obtain an analytical expression I used LaPlace transformation and got $U(s)=\frac{\exp{-0.7s}}{s^3}-\frac{\exp{-0.3s}}{s^3}+\frac{200}{s}$.

Doing the inverse LaPlace transformation yields $u(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-0.7)^2H(x-0.7)-\frac{1}{2}(x-0.3)^2H(x-0.3)+200.$

This last expression gives a straight line. However, this doesn't make sense, since we start with a heat source (the heaviside function) and we expect to heat the intervals which started at '0 degrees'. My numerical simulation confirmed this expectation.

Did I make a miscalculation somewhere, an error in the transformation or some other mistake? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your full PDE? The LT is usually only used in the time domain, because it needs a half-infinite domain. Did you do the LT in the spatial domain?

Comment: The solution process depends very much on the domain and boundary conditions. Do you have those?

Comment: The full PDE is $u_{xx} = -500(H(x-0.3)-H(x-0.7))$ with u(0)=200 and u(1)=400. Physically it should be a domain [0,1] with a flame between 0.3-0.7. The left wall stays 200K and right wall 400K.